# Close form on startup

Tags: c#

I have written an application that checks if certain files and folders exist on startup. If they don't, I call `this.Close();` (as I want to exit the **full** application). However, I am getting an error: `ObjectDisposedError` on `Application.Run(new MainForm());`. I think this has to do with calling .Close before the form loaded successfully. I am executing these startup checks from my MainForm.cs's public MainForm() function. Is that correct or do I need to place this somewhere else?

What I have tried:
Running it with a delegate and invoke:

```
public void CloseApplication() {
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(new CloseGameDelegate(CloseApplication));
    } else {
        this.Close();
    }
}
public delegate void CloseGameDelegate();
```

This still gives me the same error.

Using `Application.Exit()`: this just opens the form.

Comment: Do it in Form Load when form is fully loaded, check if files/folder exist or not, if Not, then Application.Exit()

Comment: @Pankaj and where is that? Is it an event handler? I have also found something about Application.Startup but that is undefined..

Comment: Where is the relevant code? Why are you trying to use a delegate wen the UI hasn't even started?

Comment: @pankaj this.Load works for me. However I am gonna try the answer below as that is somewhat cleaner. panagiotisKanavos I am still learning, and I used a delegate somewhere else and that worked. I do not yet know how a delegate works (guess: when used with invoke it executes the code on the same thread) and what situations I should use them, but I will.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain why? I added relevant code on which I hoped someone was able to help (and I think even without that most people will understand).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for particular files, and you don't even want to start your application if they aren't found, you could perform the check in the "Program.cs" file.

Don't bother creating and opening `MainForm` if the file(s) aren't found:

```
static void Main()
{
    ...

    var isFileFound = LookForSomeFiles();

    if (!isFileFound)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Important files were moved or removed. Please contact support.");
        return;
    }

    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}

private static bool LookForSomeFiles()
{
    // perform your check
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try that! Probably a lot cleaner and more efficient than loading a form, check stuff and close it thereafter

Comment: @TaW That was already in my code, but good point! Won't be useful if an application just doesn't start without telling the user why.